# Cast string as date and use it in comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table  as

```
NUM | TDATE   
1   | 200712    
2   | 200708    
3   | 200704    
4   | 20081210
```

where   `mytable` is created as

```
 mytable
(
  num int,
  tdate char(8)  -- legacy 
);
```

The format of tdate is YYYYMMDD.. sometimes the `date` part is optional.
So a date such as "200712" can be interpreted as 2007-12-01.

I want to write query such that i can treat `tdate` as a Date column and apply date comparison.

like

```
select num, tdate from mytable where tdate  

between '2007-12-31 00:00:00' and '2007-05-01 00:00:00'
```

So far i tried this

```
select num, tdate,
CAST(LEFT(tdate,6) 
+ COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(CAST(tdate AS VARCHAR(8)),7,8),''),'01') AS Date)
from mytable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2e7f/25)

How can I use the above converted date (3rd column ) for comparison? (needs a join?)

Also is there a better way to do this?

Edit: I have no control over the table scheme for now.. we have suggested the change to the DB team..for now have to stick with char(8) .

Comment: A downside to what you're doing is that SQLServer cannot make use of indexing, so full table scans are guaranteed regardless how narrow your between range is.

Comment: @hatchet yep i read that too.. but i have no control over the table scheme for now.. we have suggested the change to the DB team..for now have to stick with char(8)

Comment: Your `BETWEEN` will never evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this a better way to get your fixed date:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(RTRIM(tdate) + '01',8) AS DATE)
```

You can create a subquery/cte with the date cast properly:

```
;WITH cte AS (select num, tdate,CAST(LEFT(RTRIM(tdate)+ '01',8) AS DATE)'FixedDate'
              from mytable )
select num, FixedDate
from cte
where FixedDate
between '2007-12-31' and '2007-05-01'
```

Or you can just use your fixed date in the query directly:

```
select num, tdate 
from mytable 
where CAST(LEFT(RTRIM(tdate)+ '01',8) AS DATE) between '2007-12-31' and '2007-05-01'
```

Ideally you would add the fixed date field to your table so that queries can benefit from indexing the date.

Note: Be wary of `BETWEEN` with `DATETIME` as the time portion can result in undesired results if you really only care about the `DATE` portion.

Comment: CAST(LEFT(tdate + '01',8) AS DATE)  takes the year as 2020 ..i want to avoid that .. the format is always YYYYMMDD where DD is optional.. 200712 converts to 2020-07-12

Comment: I beg to differ:
`SELECT CAST(LEFT('200712' + '01',8) AS DATE)` = '2007-12-01`

Comment: Added `RTRIM()` to fix the issue with extra spaces in your data.

Comment: yep RTRIM() did the trick..must be because of char(8) is fixed length

Comment: LEFT(RTRIM()) was my first thought too. My second one is in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

`'2007-12-31 00:00:00'` > `'2007-05-01 00:00:00'`, so your `BETWEEN` clause will never return any records.

This will work, with a subquery, and with the dates flipped:

```
select num, tdate, formattedDate
from 
(
  select num, tdate
  ,
  CAST(LEFT(tdate,6) + COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(CAST(tdate AS VARCHAR(8)),7,8),''),'01') AS Date) as formattedDate

  from mytable 
) a
where formattedDate between '2007-05-01 00:00:00' and '2007-12-31 00:00:00'
```

[sqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2e7f/46)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid storing date in string type fields. If that is something you have to live with try following solution.

Since you are having `yyyymmdd` or `yyyymm` format you can first get them all in `yyyymmdd` format which is `Culture independent ISO format` and then use `style 112` to convert into Date for comparison:

```
--Culture independent solution
;with cte as (
  select num, tdate, 
         convert(date,left(rtrim(tdate) + '01',8),112) mydate --yyyymmdd format
  from mytable
)
select num,tdate,mydate
from cte
where mydate between convert(date,'20071231',112) and --Values are in yyyymmdd format
                     convert(date,'20070501',112)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to turn your string values into dates would be to use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT num, tdate
FROM mytable
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(tdate, '  ', '01') AS date) BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
;
```

If you really want to both return the converted `date` value *and* use it for filtering, you can employ `CROSS APPLY` to avoid repeating the logic:

```
SELECT t.num, t.tdate, x.date
FROM mytable AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(t.tdate, '  ', '01') AS date)) AS x (date)
WHERE x.date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
;
```

This method assumes that your `char(8)` strings are formatted as either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYYMM`, although the method will work without any changes if you decide to start using values formatted as just `YYYY` in addition to the other two formats (to imply the beginning of a year, just like a `YYYYMM` implies the beginning of a month).

Answer (score 0):

```
with date_cte(num,date)as
(select num,CAST(LEFT(tdate,6) 
+ COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(CAST(tdate AS VARCHAR(8)),7,8),''),'01') AS Date)
from mytable)

select t1.num, t1.tdate,t2.date
from mytable t1 join date_cte t2 on t1.num=t2.num
where t2.date 
between '2007-12-31 00:00:00' and '2007-05-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to test right now, but something like this may work...

```
select num, tdate
from mytable 
WHERE CAST(LEFT(tdate,6) 
+ COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(CAST(tdate AS VARCHAR(8)),7,8),''),'01') AS Date) BETWEEN CAST('2007-12-31 00:00:00' as smalldatetime) and CAST('2007-05-01 00:00:00' as smalldatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to add a date field to your table. If your table is regularly updated, fill it from the legacy field through a stored proc on a regular schedule (either trigger or job).

You'll then be able to use the date as ... a date, without all these tricks, turnarounds, and other approximations which are all potential source for confusion, mistakes and questionable results.